# Why Nullable<T> doesn't overload == opertator?

Tags: c#, .net

```
Nullable<Int32> x = 5;
Nullable<Int32> y = 10;

if (x == y) {
   ...
}
```

From my understanding, the code above will cast both `x` and `y` to `Object` and then use `Object`'s `public static bool Equals(Object objA, Object objB)` method

if my understanding is correct, then why not overload == and != operator for `Nullable<T>` as:

```
public struct Nullable<T> where T : struct {
   ...
   public static bool operator == (Nullable<T> a, Nullable<T> b) {
      ...// do some nesseary null check
      return value.Equals(other);
   }
}
```

then we can save two castings?

Comment: https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/mscorlib/system/nullable.cs

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Operators on nullable value types are actually "hardcoded" in the language spec. They are known as [Lifted Operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/expressions#lifted-operators).

> Lifted operators permit predefined and user-defined operators that operate on non-nullable value types to also be used with nullable forms of those types.

For the equality operators,

> The lifted form is constructed by adding a single `?` modifier to each operand type. The lifted operator considers two null values equal, and a null value unequal to any non-null value. If both operands are non-null, the lifted operator unwraps the operands and applies the underlying operator to produce the bool result.

This is specified in the language spec so the operators are all implemented by "compiler magic", which is why you don't see a declaration in the `Nullable` struct.

Exactly what the compiler magic does is implementation detail, but I'm pretty sure it wouldn't do a cast to `object` here, because you are using the lifted form of `==(int, int)`. According to the spec, this would apply `==(int, int)` ("the underlying operator") if both operands are not null, not `object.Equals`.

On [sharplab.io](https://sharplab.io/#v2:D4AQTAjAsAUCDMACciDCiDetaN8pARgPZEA2iAYgBQCWAdgC4D8iAhgDSL3OIECUmHHmEgA7G0QBeSbwDcQ3AF9YioA=), you can see that that version of the compiler compiles this:

```
public bool F(int? a, int? b) {
    return a == b;
}
```

to:

```
public bool F(Nullable<int> a, Nullable<int> b)
{
    Nullable<int> num = a;
    Nullable<int> num2 = b;
    return (num.GetValueOrDefault() == num2.GetValueOrDefault()) & (num.HasValue == num2.HasValue);
}
```

A generic implementation of this would be:

```
public static bool operator == (Nullable<T> a, Nullable<T> b) {
    return (a.GetValueOrDefault() == b.GetValueOrDefault()) && (a.HasValue == b.HasValue);
}
```

But note that the above is not going to compile in normal C#, because `==` is not guaranteed to be defined on `T`. However, since the lifted form `==(T?, T?)` exists *if and only if* `==(T, T)` exists, and because this is implemented by compiler magic, we're fine.

Comment: Incidentally, because of the risk of side-effects in overloaded `==`, other types have the logic flipped and test for `HasValue` first. The language spec is in [ECMA-334 11.6.2: Lifted conversions](https://www.ecma-international.org/wp-content/uploads/ECMA-334_5th_edition_december_2017.pdf)

Comment: @Sweeper thanks for your answer, just one question left, why the compiler introduces two local variables `num` and `num2`? using `a` and `b` will suffice?

Comment: @amjad That's probably an artefact of how sharplab.io translates the generated IL into C# code. The generated IL pushes the arguments onto the stack `ldarg`, then pops the arguments into local variables (`stloc`). And to call `GetValueOrDefault` and `HasValue`, it pushes the *address* of the variables (`ldloca`) first. I don't know enough IL to explain why the IL code does this.

Answer (score 1):

Your understanding is wrong. Here's what [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/nullable-value-types#lifted-operators) has to say about it:

> For the equality operator ==, if both operands are null, the result is true, if only one of the operands is null, the result is false; otherwise, the contained values of operands are compared.
>
> For the inequality operator !=, if both operands are null, the result is false, if only one of the operands is null, the result is true; otherwise, the contained values of operands are compared.

In "otherwise, the values of operands are compared" means that it'll actually use the `==` operator of `T`. If your struct does not overload such an operator, your code won't compile, just like it wouldn't without a nullable.

Comment: that statement is just a general summary without providing implementation details. For example, "otherwise, the contained values of operands are compared". But how CLR compares them?  there must be relied on `Object`'s `public static bool Equals(Object objA, Object objB)`

Comment: @amjad Why must it use the Equals method?  Why can't it, for example, use the `==` operator, just to pick some entirely arbitrary other example.  But regardless, you can run the code yourself and see which is in fact called if you want to know what happens.

Comment: @amjad `==(T?, T?)` _cannot_ rely on `Object.Equals` because that's not what the spec says. It cannot be _declared_ in `Nullable` either, because you can't declare operators _conditionally_ based on the existence of other operators in C#. `==(T?, T?)` is available iff `==(T, T)` is available. Operators for nullable value types have to be compiler magic.